# Store specific data from SPListItem data?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, splistitem

I have the following C# code:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysharepointsiteurl")
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPListItemCollection itemCollection = web.Lists["List Name"].Items;

        foreach (SPListItem item in itemCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item["Field Name"]);
            // prints 5 different results.
        }
    web.Dispose();
}
site.Dispose();
```

Is there anyway I can get, say the 4th printed out result, and store it in a string? I'm sure there is a way but I can't seem to work it out. Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: There is no need to explicitly dispose of the site/web, the `using` is specifically there to do that.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't copy/paste the code since it's on another machine. This is purely from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the indexer to get the item at a given position:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysharepointsiteurl"))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    var items = web.Lists["List Name"].GetItems("Field Name");
    string value = (string)items[3]["Field Name"];
}
```

Comment: Although I made one small edit, instead of: `var items = web.Lists["List Name"].GetItems("Field Name");` I used `var items = web.Lists["List Name"].Items;` as otherwise it threw an ArgumentException.